# display a gif after it has been loaded

Tags: javascript

So I have a `<img  onload="resizeImage()" src="movie.gif">` on my website and I only want to show it after it has been fully loaded. The gif is loaded from my sql database through php so the img src is different from page to page. I also have a resize to make the image fullsize

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function resizeImage()
{
  var window_height = document.body.clientHeight
  var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth
  var image_width   = document.images[0].width
  var image_height  = document.images[0].height
  var height_ratio  = image_height / window_height
  var width_ratio   = image_width / window_width
  if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
  {
    document.images[0].style.width  = "auto"
    document.images[0].style.height = "100%"
  }
  else
  {
    document.images[0].style.width  = "100%"
    document.images[0].style.height = "auto"
  }
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to put the gif in a div and do this

```
#div {
     display:none;
{
```

and then after the image is loaded change the div to this

```
#div {
     display:block;
{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this HTML:

```
<img src="movie.gif" onload="displayImage(this)" style="display:none;">
```

with this javascript:

```
function displayImage(obj) {
    obj.style.display = "block";
}
```

The other way to do it without event handlers in the HTML is to dynamically create the object and only insert it into the page once it's loaded like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(this);
};
img.src = "movie.gif";
```

Or, you could also create it dynamically, insert it into the DOM immediately, but only make it visible once loaded:

```
var img = new Image();
img.style.display = "none";
img.onload = function() {
    this.style.display = "block";
};
img.src = "movie.gif";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

---

OK, now that you've shown your actual code and HTML, here's an answer that considers that additional information and uses your existing code:

Make your HTML be this:

```
<img onload="resizeImage(this)" src="movie.gif" style="display:none;">
```

Change your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function resizeImage(obj)
{
  var window_height = document.body.clientHeight;
  var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth;
  var image_width   = obj.width;
  var image_height  = obj.height;
  var height_ratio  = image_height / window_height;
  var width_ratio   = image_width / window_width;
  if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
  {
    obj.style.width  = "auto";
    obj.style.height = "100%";
  }
  else
  {
    obj.style.width  = "100%";
    obj.style.height = "auto";
  }
  obj.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish - you're not right.  onload handlers will always fire when done inline like this, even if the image is already cached.  See my comment on your answer.  You CANNOT apply the event handler later in javascript.  That's where you can miss the event entirely.  In fact, in IE you will miss the event with your code EVERYTIME in IE if the image is already cached.

Comment: Alright, I'll go with that assumption, but. I have to check (since that's not been my experience, but it could be that I have not tried the inline handler).

Comment: Alright then: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Ea2sZ/ Mea culpa; there *is* sometimes a reason to use inline handlers. Fancy that. (You're also missing a quotation.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I added two other options that don't need inline handlers, but they work by creating the image dynamically in code and not having it in the page HTML.

Comment: All three (with a tweak to the last): http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Ea2sZ/1/ Learn something new everyday.

Comment: I forgot to say that the gif is loaded from my sql database through php so the img.src is different from page to page

Comment: @RicoKing - The first option works fine no matter what the image URL is.  The second two options require your javascript to know what the image URL is.  You can have your server put the image filename into a javascript variable when it renders the page and your javascript can pick up the filename from the JS variable.

Comment: @jfriend00 Cool thanks but how would I sort out onload="" because I am already using it for the resize?

Comment: @RicoKing - I don't understand what you mean that you're already using `onload` for resize.  If you mean you have some other code that runs when the image is loaded, then just call two functions from one event handler.  If you're using either of the last two options, you can install multiple event listeners with `addEventListener()` or `attachEvent()` instead of just one `onload` handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry there, I have added the code to what it looks like on my page. Thanks for the help bro

Comment: @RicoKing - I added an answer that uses your existing code to the end of my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you so much bro it works perfect. Go on freelancer.com and make lots of money!

Comment: @RicoKing - since you're new here on StackOverflow, do you realize that, when someone provides a good answer to your question, you should indicate that by checking the green mark to the left of the answer to indicate that this answered your question.  And, it rewards the answerer with some reputation points and earns you some reputation points for following the proper procedure on StackOverflow.